# Karaf: Missing Constraint in bundle

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I am trying to wrap dnsjava as a bundle in Karaf. When I try to start the bundle I get a "Missing Constraint" error. I looked in the dnsjava code and found that the only place android is referenced is in a Class.forName. So I am wondering what causes this problem and how can I get around it. I am pretty certain that the class is not referenced in the code anywhere.

Here is the exception:

```
 opendaylight-user@root>bundle:start 288
 Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
Unable to execute command on bundle 288: The bundle "dnsjava_2.1.8 [288]"    could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: android.os; version="0.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer. There is an Import in the MANIFEST.MF that requires android.os.